# CSS: size of the elements changes in a very strange way in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've faced with strange problem that I noticed only in Google Chrome: element size (images, inner tables) changes when inspect it via developer tools.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open Chrome developers tools.
2. Open elements
3. Select from element hierarchy any element that contains table table#inner

**Result**: element increase size on each selecting of it (means element), till it achieve the specified size

**Linked Problem**: table#inner must change own size due size of table#outer td element, but it doesn't

Code example: 
**page.jsp**

```
<div id="outer_div">
<table id="outer">
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table id="inner">
        ......
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
#inner {
  width: auto; // or 100%;
}
```

with: 300px; work fine )

P.S. In Firefox all works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean #inner should occupy the size of #outer
then,

```
#inner {
    min-width:100%;
}
```

or

```
#inner {
    width:100%;
}
```